# ¿Cómo conocer la categoría de un producto de un pedido woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Intento **contar los productos de sólo una categoría** que ha comprado el usuario

La idea es: acceder a todos los post creados por el usuario que sean órdenes de Woocommerce, acceder a cada órden, revisar en la órden el producto, y revisar si el producto es de la categoría que yo quiero, y entonces ya acciono un *if* con mis necesidades.

Para ello utilizo el siguiente script:

```
function identificar_paquete( $lleva_creados ) {
$lleva_comprados = 0;    

// Obtenemos todos los pedidos del cliente
$pedidos = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
    'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
) );    

// De cada pedido, obtenemos sus elementos, entre los cuales buscaremos el paquete que ha comprado. y sumaré los regalos que ha comprado en total
foreach ($pedidos as $pedido)
{
    $datos_del_pedido = new WC_Order($pedido->ID);

    // Obtengo los elementos/información de cada línea de pedido
    $lineas_pedido = $datos_del_pedido->get_items();
    foreach ($lineas_pedido as $linea_pedido)
    {
        // Primero checo que el producto tenga la categoría regalo
        if ( $linea_pedido->has_term( 'regalo') ):
        // Reviso los items de la línea de pedido, en busca del ID del paquete. Reviso también la version de WooCommerce
            // WC 3+ compatibility
            if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ):
                $id_del_producto = $linea_pedido['product_id'];
            else:
                $id_del_producto = $linea_pedido->get_product_id();
            endif;
            // Reviso a qué paquete se corresponde este id de producto
            if ( $id_del_producto == '1' ):
                $lleva_comprados = $lleva_comprados + 5;
            elseif ( $id_del_producto == '2' ):
                $lleva_comprados = $lleva_comprados + 10;
            elseif ( $id_del_producto == '3' ):
                $lleva_comprados = $lleva_comprados + 25;
            endif;
        endif;

    } // foreach de lineas de pedido
}  // foreach de cada pedido

$le_quedan_para_hacer = $lleva_comprados - $lleva_creados;
return ( $le_quedan_para_hacer );
```

}

Esto me arroja el error:
Call to Undefined method WC_Order_Item_Product:has_term()

¿Estoy utilizando mal has_term()?
¿cómo puedo conocer la categoría de un producto comprado por el usuario?
Muchas gracias

Comment: No trabajo con WooCommerce, pero quizá lo que necesites invocar sea el método `get_type`, cambiando esto: `if ( $linea_pedido->has_term( 'regalo') ):` por esto: **`if ( $linea_pedido->get_type()== 'regalo'):`**  Si no es eso lo que quieres, [revisa entre los métodos de la clase](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) cuál es el que hace lo que buscas. En cuanto a `has_term()` es un método propio de los posts de WP. También puedes intentar así: **`if ( $linea_pedido->is_type('regalo') ):`**

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu respuesta, sucede que al analizar mejor el código me di cuenta de que en realidad no necesito saber la categoría, pues lo que realmente me importa es si compró el producto con determinada ID
Y el problema que realmente tengo es que no me devuelve $lleva_comprados

Comment: Eso parece estar bien. ¿Qué devuelve, cero, o no devuelve nada?

Comment: No devuelve nada en absoluto

Comment: ¿Quizá ni siquiera esté entrando en la función `identificar_paquete`? Es lo primero que debería depurar, poniendo que devuelva algo arbitrario provisionalmente.

Comment: Pues ya probé declarándolo previamente y pasándolo como parámetro a la función, y no se procesa ni es devuelto con un return
Incluso ya escribí la función en la misma plantilla del tema en lugar del archivo de funciones, y nada...

Comment: La pregunta entonces es: ¿desde dónde y como llamas a la función? Deberías tener un hook, un shortcode o algo así en tu plantilla y enlazarlo con un `add_action` que llame a la función. Debes explicar cómo estás haciendo eso para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Escribí la función directamente en la plantilla.  
Primero justo después de <?php. declaré $lleva_comprados, y  en la siguiente línea escribí la función.
No lo llamo con hooks